# Read text and add to list

Tags: java

I am working on a method that takes a scanner as a parameter, and the values of the text file should be added to the doublyLinkedList. Right now the method is working fine but i have an issue where if it encounters a string in the text file, it stops. I want it in such a way that i skip over any line that has a string i tried using the nextLine() but it didnt work.

```
      public static void addList(Scanner input, DoublyLinkedList list){

      Number data=null;
       if(input.hasNextLine()){
        
         if(input.hasNextInt()){
            data=input.nextInt();
            list.addEnd(data);
            parseScanner(input, list);
        } 

        else if(input.hasNext()){
            input.hasNext();
        }
                    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The last line in your code is `input.hasNext();` Shouldn't that be `input.next();` ?

Comment: As it is, the else-clause is an infinite loop. ``Scanner@hasNext()`` does not consume any characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `hasNextInt()` method of the [scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()). If this method will return false, you can just read string and then again try to read int.

```java
if (input.hasNextInt()) {
   // read int
} else {
   input.nextLine(); // skip line that is not a number
}
```

Comment: readLine() is undefined for scanner . I think that works only with bufferedreader ? Correct me if I’m wrong

Comment: Sorry, I mean `nextLine();`. Thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 0):

I think in.hasNext() should be input.hasNext()

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, just edited it

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?